# NestJS / Prisma 5, PrismaClient.$on() gives "string not assignable to type never"

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

I'm using the sample code directly from the prisma.io site and it worked for prisma version 4.16 but no longer works for Prisma 5

```
import { INestApplication, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient {
  async enableShutdownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
    this.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
      await app.close();
    });
  }
}
```

I tried compiling the code but that fails with a "string not assignable to type never" error. What am I missing?

Comment: the nestjs docs is out of date, see https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/2822

Answer (score 1):

Remove enableShutdownHooks:

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }
}
```

In your main.ts add this line:

```
app.enableShutdownHooks();
```

Source: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/upgrade-guides/upgrading-versions/upgrading-to-prisma-5#removal-of-the-beforeexit-hook-from-the-library-engine